# How do I enforce that every single data element in my database schema has a unique name?

Tags: sql, naming-conventions

I've read about a principle that states the following: “Every single data element should have a unique name in your database schema.” (http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/439341-name-keyword) How do you enforce that?

A usual technique consists in placing a three-character abbreviation before the meaningful name of the column. So, Employee.Name becomes Emp_Name. So far, so good. However, Employer.Name should also become Emp_Name. So, I must come up with some cryptic abbreviation for Employer that makes little sense. Let's say, “Eml”. And, as the Schema becomes bigger, more and more efforts have to be devoted to avoid collision.

In my opinion, a good compromise would consist in always using sensible prefixes. This way, we avoid MOST of the collisions without using unintuitive abbreviations – like “Eml” for Employer.

Comment: you could employ a policy of always checking to see whether an entity with a proposed name already exists before creating it

Comment: On a style point, I disagree with the idea that no two columns should share the same name - they can easily be disambiguated by using aliases in queries. I also think repeating the table/entity name inside the column is superfluous, i.e. dbo.Customer.CustomerId, dbo.Customer.CustomerName. Why not just Id and Name? Just my humble opinion tho!

Comment: Yes, Paul, but policies require much effort, especially when there are many people working on the project. And policies would not prevent unintuitive abbreviations, like "Eml", mentioned above.

Comment: Matt. If you follow the principle, It's far easier to find and replace, while mantaining the code. And you avoid collisions with present and future keywords.

Furthermore, when you execute a query, you usually receive just the name of the column, with no qualifier, unless you take the effort to explicitly define aliases for the columns.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement that every data element have a unique name should *not* be interpreted as every column having a unique name.

Foreign keys, in particular, should have the same name based on the table they are referencing.  So, `CustomerID` would mean the same thing wherever it occurs.  It would be the reference to the primary key to the `Customer` table.  And I would call the primary key in the table `CustomerID`, although sometimes I also see it as just `ID`.

There are some other cases were duplicate names are ok.  All tables I create have metadata on each row, describing when and who created the row.  These are called `CreatedAt` and `CreatedBy` respectively.  These are in all tables, but are not part of the logical data model.

Another case of duplicate names that comes to mind is effective and end date on slowly changing dimensions.  It is usually simpler to just call these `EffDate` and `EndDate` (or whatever), rather than trying to make them unique.

Finally, I do a lot of processing using data flow methods which involve multiple staging tables.  I very intentionally keep column names the same for tracking purposes.

However, the answer to your question is to use prefixes related to the table.  The data elements unique to that table can have a short prefix so we know what they are.  For instance, `Cust_Name` and `Addr_City` are sensible names for the customer name in the customer table and the city name in the address table.

Comment: I really appreciate that you took the time to answer, but your response has not been helpful. I already knew that data element is not exactly the same as column, though I didn't consider it relevant here.

And the short prefix idea is the same I had already mentioned, so it doesn't bring anything knew to the discussion.